# implicit operator on two different classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop

How can i perform implicit operator from 2 different class ?

```
public class A
{
    public int one { get; set; }
    public int two { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator A(B v)
    {
        \\one = v.one; \\ static Error.
        \\this.one = v.one; \\ Error
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int one { get; set; }
    public int two { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    a = b;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use explicit cast operator for transforming B into A, since some data is lost (Name and LastName)

Comment: @vtortola No.  It's an implicit operator, so it creates an implicit conversion.  It doesn't stop you from creating a losses implicit conversion; it can't possibly know that you've even done so.  It's just a bad idea to do that.

Comment: I thought it was a requirement : "The implicit keyword is used to declare an implicit user-defined type conversion operator. Use it to enable implicit conversions between a user-defined type and another type, if the conversion is guaranteed not to cause a loss of data."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: On the other hand: "If a conversion operation can cause exceptions or lose information, you should mark it explicit. This prevents the compiler from silently invoking the conversion operation with possibly unforeseen consequences." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

Comment: @vtortola That doesn't state it's a requirement, but it is a very good guideline to follow. A better option here is probably to use a common interface.

Comment: @vtortola Yes, like I said, you *should* make it explicit.  The compiler of course can't know whether the conversion is lossy or not though, so it has to trust you to write your operators sensibly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a new instance of `A` in the implicit conversion:

```
public class A
{
    public int one { get; set; }
    public int two { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator A(B v)
    {
        return new A
        {
            one = v.one,
            two = v.two
        };
    }
}
```